# What is special about 2 in Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory

I have very little experience with number theory and I am not in a place to read through Wiles' proof of Fermat's Last Theorem right now. However, I do want to get just a little bit of understanding of why 2 is different than other numbers in the context of the proof. To be more specific, presumably, at some point in Wiles' proof he must state a lemma or proposition or something that holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ other than 2 (or something like that) so that his proof does not rule out the existence of Pythagorean triples. What is that lemma/proposition/step where 2 is excluded in such a way that Wiles' proof does not imply that Pythagorean triples are impossible?

To further clarify, I can give an example of the type of answer I am looking for. If I were asking about what makes 5 special when it comes to the unsolvability of the quintic (i.e why all of a sudden at degree 5 do general polynomial equations become unsolvable?), I would be looking for an answer roughly on the level of "$A_5$ is the smallest alternating group which is simple. The simplicity of $A_n$ for $n\geq 5$ is what makes quintics (and higher degree polynomials) fundamentally different from quartics and lower degree polynomials, and allows us to use Galois Theory to show that these higher degree polynomials are unsolvable."

So, what is it that separates 2 from every other number when it comes to Fermat's Last Theorem?

Comment: What separates $2$ in $x^n+y^n=z^n$ from other $n$? That we have non-trivial integer solutions by [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) for $n=2$. Also $n=1$ has a lot of integer solutions. So not only $2$ is special, but also $1$.

Comment: Also the fact that there are considerably more integers than squares which are considerably more than cubes etc, so it is much easier for the sum of two squares to be anything (in particular a square) than for the sum of three cubes to be anything (in particular a cube)

Comment: This might be a question for Math Overflow instead. It sounds like you want an understanding of why Wiles' proof dismisses the $n = 2$ case. While you may find someone to answer that here, I think you'd have better luck finding someone with such specialist knowledge on Overflow.

Comment: @TheoBendit I am also on MO and my experience is that such questions are not considered research level, because they are too broad and not specific in the technical details. The comparison "on the level of $A_5$" is not sufficient here.

Comment: Please be more explicit about how "2 is different from other numbers" in the context of Fermat's Last Theorem.  If you are about to start studies leading to a math Ph.D., practice in articulating your meaning will prove valuable.

Comment: I am intentionally keeping it somewhat vague, partially because I really am not familiar with Wiles' proof, partially so that people can answer how they see fit. But presumably, at some point in the proof, there is some proposition or lemma which holds for all natural numbers other than 2, or something like that, so that the proof does not rule out the existence of pythagorean triples.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear, and is necessarily a bit vague. I'd also like to hear an answer.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thank you but I should note (and probably should have a few minutes ago) that I edited the question to include basically the contents of my previous comment.

Comment: This really boils down to asking why the curve $$y^2=x(x-a^2)(x-b^2)$$ (for $a^2+b^2$ a perfect square) is **not** particularly interesting - in contrast, that is, with [the (nonexistent) Frey curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frey_curve). Note that I say this without knowing anything whatsoever about the topic; the point is just that since the shape of the proof of FLT is "the curve associated to a counterexample yileds a contradiction to Taniyama-Shimura," we know that the analogous curves associated to Pythagorean triples are fundamentally different. To say more I'd need to know things.

Comment: For n=2, the Fermat equation admits an infinite number of integral solutions, the Pythagorician triples, all explicitly known. The difference with n>2 lies in the genus of the Fermat affine curve (say  F_n, with equation x^n+y^n=1), which is g=(n-1)(n-2)/2. For n=2, g=0 and F_2 is a circle, the parametrization of which gives all the rational points, hence the pythagorician triples. For n>3, g>3, and the Mordell conjecture (proved by Faltings 1983-84) states that the number of rational points is finite. But Faltings proof is not effective. NB: for n=3, g=3 and F_3 is an elliptic curve.

Comment: But note that F_3 has nothing to do with the (non existent) Hellegouarch -Frey elliptic curve which allowed to connect the Fermat problem to the Shimura-Taniyama-Weil conjecture (proved by Wiles et al.) on the modularity of elliptic curves defined over Q.